# Windows 10, how to enable bluetooth connections?

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10, I found my bluetooth devices were no longer paired.

All my searches online instruct me to do things in the `settings > bluetooth menu.` But, it seems my settings menu has no bluetooth menu.

Below is a shot of my settings menu, followed by a shot from the a example of the types of solutions I found, also linked below.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Where do I find/enable this bluetooth settings menu?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/fix-connections-to-bluetooth-audio-devices-and-wireless-displays#v1h=tab01

Comment: Do you even see the bluetooth device in Device Manager ? Install the driver if missing

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? I am working on fixing this issue for a recently purchased Toshiba Laptop which came designed for Windows 10.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with my desktop's built in bluetooth adapter. It worked after I purchased a usb bluetooth adapter and installed the appropriate drivers.

Comment: You had to buy an additional piece of hardware to fix something that used to work? Now that's an upgrade!

Answer (score -1):

You need to open the device manager.  This is the way I usually find it, although there are a number of different ways.  Click the action center icon (the icon to the left of the little keyboard) click connect, click find other types of devices, click device manager.  In the device manager you should see the Bluetooth icon.  Give it a right click and click enable.  I'm not sure why but windows 10 likes to disable the Bluetooth for no apparent reason.  This happens to me once a week.

Comment: Could you possibly include a couple of screenshots documenting this process?